# UIButton default tap fade animation missing in UITableViewController custom cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom cell with a few UIButtons in it. I have created Target Actions like so on the buttons:

```
[cell.customLocationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customLocationButtonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The actions work great though I don't see the default iOS fade animation on the UIButtons? Is there something I need to enable to get those too - I thought they were standard when using a UIButton from IB?

Comment: show your customLocationButton initialization part

Comment: I don't initialize. I din't think you needed to initialize when using IB?

Comment: Just Use the type of **UIButtonTypeSystem** for your  **customLocationButton**.. Hope that the **customLocationButton** as of Custom type.

Comment: the button type is a read-only property. In IB it is already set to System

Answer (score 15):

Had the same problem. I could get the button to change color on highlight with `setTitleColor:forState:`, but it didn't fade from highlight to normal state like the other system buttons.

Turns out that's because my button was of type `UIButtonTypeCustom`. Switching it to `UIButtonTypeSystem` solved it for me. Please note I'm running this on iOS9.

Here's a snippet (**Swift**) that assumes `self` is a `UIView` or subclass:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .System)
button.setTitle("Title", forState: .Normal)
button.sizeToFit() // Sizes the button frame based on the title.
addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 7):

I've been searching all over the internet and finally I've found a solution from a post on StackOverFlow check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35479755/8355464).

For Swift 4 You can add this UIButton extension and it will work fine.

```
extension UIButton {

    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isHighlighted = true
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    override open func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isHighlighted = false
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }

    override open func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isHighlighted = false
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    }

}
```

Comment: That's genius, with an override of isHighlighted it is way faster than doing animation on the touches methods !

Answer (score 4):

I found this solution:

```
setTitleColor(UIColor.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.3), for: .highlighted)
```

It's really simple and works perfectly.

Comment: Simple, fast and accurate. Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you probably initialized the button like this:

```
let button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: <width>, height: <height>)
```

try to do it like this:

```
let button = UIButton.init(type: .system)
button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: <width>, height: <height>)
```

The "fade" animation on tap, comes with **system** style, after init the button you can customize it.

Answer (score 0):

In your XIB inside attribute inspector select your button and then inside button type you will get follow option you can select and change your button look and feel accordingly:-

[image]

Comment: Yes in system you need to set but if you want some other animations then you need to use CABasicAnimation

Comment: If I drag out a button and place it directly in the default view of a VC I get a basic fade animation on tap. This is without setting up any custom animation.

When I'm using a button in a custom cell - do I then need to add the CABasicAnimation layer manually?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is:

**Swift:**

```
button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: .Selected)
```